# Best way to get Amazon page and product information

Tags: java, web-scraping

I want to get Amazon page and product information from their website so I work on a future project. I have no experience with APIs but also saw that I would need to pay in order to use Amazon's. My current plan was to use a WebRequest class which basically takes down the page's raw text and then parse through it to get what I need. It pulls down HTML from all the websites I have tried except amazon. When I try and use it for amazon I get text like this...

??èv~-1?½d!Yä90û?¡òk6??ªó?l}L??A?{í??j?ì??ñF Oü?ª[D ú7W¢!?É?L?]â  v??ÇJ???t?ñ?j?^,Y£>O?|?I`OöN??Q?»bÇJPy1·¬Ç??RtâU??Q%vB??^íè|??ª?

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Or even better if you could point me towards a better way of doing this? Any help is appreciated.

This is the class I mentioned...

public class WebRequest {

```
protected String url;
protected ArrayList<String> pageText;

public WebRequest() {
    url = "";
    pageText = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public WebRequest(String url) {
    this.url = url;
    pageText = new ArrayList<String>();
    load();
}

public boolean load() {
    boolean returnValue = true;

    try {
        URL thisURL = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(thisURL.openStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            pageText.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        returnValue = false;
        System.out.println("peepee");
    }

    return returnValue;
}

public boolean load(String url) {
    this.url = url;
    return load();
}

public String toString() {
    String returnString = "";
    for (String s : pageText) {
        returnString += s + "\n";
    }

    return returnString;
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Make sure to specifiy the correct encoding, do not use the platform default encoding. Try UTF-8.

Comment: Sadly did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the page is returned using a different character encoding than your platform default. If that's the case, you should specify the appropriate encoding, e.g:

```
new InputStreamReader(thisURL.openStream(), "UTF-8")
```

But that data doesn't look like character data at all to me. It's too random. It looks like binary data. Are you sure you're not downloading an image by mistake?

If you want to make more sophisticated HTTP requests, there are quite a few Java libraries, e.g. [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) and [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).

But it's worth bearing in mind that Amazon probably doesn't like people scraping its site, and will have built in detection of malicious or unwanted activity.  It might be sending you gibberish on purpose to deter you from continuing. You should be careful because some big sites may block your IP temporarily or permanently.

My advice would be to learn how to use the Amazon APIs. They're pretty powerful—and you won't get yourself banned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Changing it to UTF-8 did not work :( I will take some time and learn the AWS system and see if I can get it to work for me.